# Twilio register only the numbers already verified in Twilio portal

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

I am having a strange requirement where I need to make sure the clients using my app must be already verified on Twilio. Here's the workflow I need:
Consider you are using Twilio trial account, you need to have your number already added and verified on [Twilio Console](http://%20https://www.twilio.com/console/phone-numbers/verified), to receive SMS.

I need to replicate similar functionality when using a paid account with Twilio, where I need to disallow receiving SMS on any numbers not added to the above page. I was thinking to implement the following workflow:

1) When a user requests a signup using my app, the client (or server) will query Twilio to check if the number is already added to the Twilio Verified Caller IDs or not.

2) If not, display error and stop further actions on the app.

3) If yes, continue to verify the user and proceed to signup.

For above workflow, I need an API to see if a number is there in the verified caller id list or not. I have gone through the available API docs (Authy, SMS, Verification) but couldn't find anything regarding it. 
I also went through the TwimlBin documentation but couldn't find anything there too.

I want to know if this is achievable by any method or not? Can someone please guide me how to do this if it is possible at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

When you want to work with numbers that are verified with your account, you need the [Outgoing Caller IDs resource](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/voice/outgoing-caller-ids). You can check a number exists on the list of verified outgoing caller IDs by [listing the numbers and filtering by the number](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/voice/outgoing-caller-ids#outgoingcallerids-list-resource) you are looking for.

In Node.js this would look a bit like:

```
const accountSid = 'your_account_sid';
const authToken = 'your_auth_token';
const client = require('twilio')(accountSid, authToken);

const numberToCheck = "THE_NUMBER";

client.api
  .accounts(accountSid)
  .outgoingCallerIds.list({ phoneNumber: numberToCheck })
  .then(callerIds => {
    if (callerIds.length > 0) {
      // Yay, this number is on the list!
    } else {
      // This number is not verified. Stop here.
    }
  });
```

Let me know if this helps at all.

Comment: Hi @philnash, thanks for the quick reply. I believe this will solve my problem. I will get back to you in some time.

Comment: It helped! Thanks a lot for the guidance @philansh.